# Script in where it copies a sheet's data, and pastes it, but over pastes

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my script.

```
Sub Update_OOR()

    Dim wsTNO As Worksheet
    Dim wsTND As Worksheet
    Dim wsTNA As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long

    Set wsTNO = Sheets("Tel-Nexx OOR")
    Set wsTND = Sheets("Tel-Nexx Data")
    Set wsTNA = Sheets("Tel-Nexx Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Intersect(wsTNO.UsedRange, wsTNO.Columns("S"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:P"))
            .Copy wsTNA.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With


'Blow away rows that are useless
    lastrow = wsTND.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    wsTND.Range("O1:P1").Copy wsTND.Range("O2:P" & lastrow)
    wsTND.UsedRange.Copy Sheets.Add.Range("A1")

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("P"))
        ActiveSheet.Range("O:P").Calculate
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = wsTND.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A2:M" & lastrow)).Copy wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Delete
    End With

    With wsTNO
        lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsTNO.Range("T1:AD1").Copy
        wsTNO.Range("B3:N" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
        fstcell = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        wsTNO.Range("AE1:AI1").Copy wsTNO.Range("O" & fstcell & ":S" & lastrow).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

It technically works perfectly till here:

```
With wsTNO
        lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsTNO.Range("T1:AD1").Copy
        wsTNO.Range("B3:N" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
        fstcell = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        wsTNO.Range("AE1:AI1").Copy wsTNO.Range("O" & fstcell & ":S" & lastrow).Offset(1, 0)
End With
```

Now technically everything in this part works correctly, but the last line in the code, it pasts everything correctly, then it goes one step beyond. I'd like to know why. If I get rid of the offset it overwrites what is in the cell above in O through S. I need to know the first and last cell, because the data needs to be only written to a specific cell range.

If there is an easier way of doing this it be appreciated if someone could tell me, if not then can someone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks.

Attached is the workbook.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/First%26LastRows.xlsm

Comment: when I step through your code, fstcell becomes 45, and lastrow becomes 2 at the line you have highlighted. I wonder if having the range defined from the bottom up is affecting your offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd piece of code add + 1 to

```
 lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
```

So you have

```
 lastrow = wsTNO.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

The former gives you row 2, which is your header row. What you want is row 3, the row right after your headers.

**Update: To Show How To Test in Future**

Although the **.Select** method is typically frowned upon. It can be great for testing / debugging. I ran

```
wsTNO.Range("O" & fstcell & ":S" & lastrow).Select
```

in the immediate window after I set lastrow and fstcell to find the range that was set. Therefore I knew you didn't want to copy your headers. From there you can figure out what is driving that range to be set and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I was wondering if that was possible or not, how come this stuff never seems to be on the web when you need it, I looked through over a few dozen sheets. Thanks a lot!

Comment: see my Edit to help yourself debug this stuff in the future.

Comment: Trust me I've recorded that for future purposes, again, thanks a lot.